# Is Wake on Magic Packet a security risk?

Tags: windows-10, security, sleep, magic-packet

After converting to Windows 10 a while ago, I have been disturbed in my sleep by my computer randomly turning on during the middle of the night. I opened CMD with Admin priveleges, and entered `powerconfig/devicequery wake_armed` . This let me see which devices have permission to automatically wake the PC. In this list were my mouse and keyboard, and my NIC (Realtek PCIe controller).

I am not sure why my NIC would have wake privileges by default, this seems sketchy to me. I went into the Advanced settings for the device, and sure enough both the "Wake on pattern match" and "Wake on magic packet" were enabled. After brief research, it seems like something akin to a broadcast packet being heard on my interface was enough to wake the PC. I disabled them mainly because I want to sleep without being woken up myself in the middle of the night. Now I am concerned about the security of my PC, because I do not understand enough about why magic packets are considered or from where magic packets originate.

I have three questions thus:

1. What is "Wake on Pattern Match"?
2. What is "Wake on Magic Packet"?
3. Could a malicious entity abuse this?

Answer (score 3):

> I opened CMD with Admin priveleges, and entered powerconfig/devicequery wake_armed . This let me see which devices have permission to automatically wake the PC. In this list were my mouse and keyboard, and my NIC (Realtek PCIe controller).

That's not actually a complete list – there's one device that can wake the system but is never listed there, namely your RTC (the computer's hardware clock). The OS can program it to wake the system at some future time, e.g. to run a scheduled task or install Windows updates overnight. You can use `powercfg /waketimers` to check whether there are any RTC wakeup requests.

In recent Windows versions, the "UpdateOrchestrator" has been known to wake the OS from sleep through a Task Scheduler job (one which Microsoft deliberately makes very difficult to disable), and even to keep the OS from suspending automatically (apparently due to a bug that was fixed in October's update).

You should use `powercfg /lastwake` or `Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter -Newest 5 | fl Message` to check what actually triggered the resume from sleep.

> What is "Wake on Magic Packet"?

A packet that specifically requests Wake-on-LAN – it [has your MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) in it 16 times in a specific format. Most "Wake on LAN" tools send it through UDP, but the specific protocol doesn't matter so long as it gets delivered to the NIC.

This feature is safe to use; there are many Windows apps for Wake-on-LAN that generate such packets (e.g. [this one](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html)).

> What is "Wake on Pattern Match"?

In addition to the fixed-format magic packet, the NIC can be configured to recognize a few custom patterns. Typically Windows sets up patterns to match e.g. ARP requests for your LAN IPv4 address, Neighbour Discovery requests for your IPv6 address, NetBIOS name lookups for your computer name, and so on – basically packets that indicate that some other device wants to connect to you.

The idea is that your computer would wake whenever you want to access it, then go to sleep again when idle. For example, you could have a PC serving as a file server or Remote Desktop server, which would *normally* require it to be running 24/7, but with "Wake on pattern match" it could sleep most of the time and still be reachable.

In practice, unfortunately, "Wake on pattern match" only works when you least want it to, but never does when you actually need it. It's a very common source of unwanted wakes, although *not* the only one.

> Could a malicious entity abuse this?

Only to the extent of slighly annoying you. Literally the only thing they could do is wake a sleeping computer, but they cannot gain any access that they wouldn't have if you had powered it on yourself.

Personally I disable "Wake on Pattern Match" but keep "Wake on Magic Packet" enabled – it's least likely to be triggered by accident. (In addition, due to IPv4 NAT, it is difficult to send a WoL packet across the Internet even when people *want* to get it working, so you can pretty much consider it to be limited to the LAN.)